# ¿Cómo hago para sustituir una linea por otra de un archivo .conf desde un script?

Tags: linux, script

Por ejemplo, tengo las lineas:

```
bind 127.0.0.1  
tcp-keepalive 0
```

Debo cambiar el valor de la segunda, para lo que usé el siguiente comando:

```
sudo sed -i 's/tcp-keepalive 0/tcp-keepalive 60/g' etc/redis/redis.conf
```

Pero, en el caso de que haya sido cambiado anteriormente por otro valor, no se encontraría `tcp-keepalive 0` y no cambiaría nada.

La pregunta sería por tanto, ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la línea sin importar el valor actual que tenga (porque fue modificada anteriormente)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Codigo

```
sed -i 's/tcp-keepalive [0-9]*/tcp-keepalive 50/g' /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

#### Resultado

```
bind 127.0.0.1  
tcp-keepalive 50
```

---

### Explicacion

En este codigo, hemos usado una **expresion regular**, para poder "*atrapar*" los numeros que se encuentren despues de la palabra `tcp-keepalive`, sin importar el valor que tengan.

```
[0-9]*
```

Significaria algo como:

> Coincide con todos los numeros que se encuentren entre 0 a 9 y que se repitan multiples veces.

Comment: OK muchas gracias.  En otro caso se podría hacer también con un valor de caracteres??

Comment: En teoria, todo lo controlan las expresiones regulares

Comment: Recuerda que si la pregunta te sirvio puedes aceptarla haciendo click en el ✓ al lado de mi respuesta